# Efficiently computing all equivariant maps between two $GL_n$-representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, computation

This is sort of a strange question; if it's not appropriate for MathOverflow I apologize in advance.

I'm in a situation where I'd like to be able to give a computer two $GL_n$ representations $V$ and $W$ and compute a basis the subspace of $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ consisting of all the $GL_n$-equivariant maps. I'd like a basis that's as explicit as possible --- consisting of actual matrices. We can say that $V$ and $W$ are given in terms of a square matrix of polynomials in $n^2$ variables specifying the action of $GL_n$, though in my case I actually just want $\mathrm{Hom}_G(\mathbb{S}_\nu(\mathbb{C}^n), \mathbb{S}_\lambda(\mathbb{C}^n)\otimes\mathbb{S}_\mu(\mathbb{C}^n))$ for some partitions $\lambda,\mu,\nu$. ($\mathbb{S}_\lambda$ is the Schur functor.) I'm happy to just handle this case. (Obviously I know how to find the solution abstractly, but I'd like an actual basis of actual matrices.)

I have a bad, slow way to do this in Macaulay2 already which seems to work. Say $V=\mathbb{S}_\nu(\mathbb{C}^n)$ is irreducible. We look at the map from $\mathrm{Hom}(V,W)$ to itself given by $T\mapsto gT-Tg$. We think of this as a map from $R^{\oplus(\dim V\cdot\dim W)}$ to itself, where $R$ is a polynomial ring in $n^2$ variables, and take its kernel as a map of modules. Then the submodule we want is the $|\nu|$-graded part of this kernel.

This is quite slow, and it also feels like it's computing more than I need, but I can't come up with anything that's any faster. (The other idea I had was to take that matrix of polynomials and look for the subspace where each coefficient is zero. This is even slower.) Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: Consider the action of the raising operator $e_{i,i+1}$ on the $\nu$ weight space of $V_\lambda \otimes V_\mu$ (taking it to the $\nu + \alpha_i$ weight space). You want the common kernel of these $n-1$ operators.

Comment: I suspect Allen's answer is the best. Also, Howe, Tan and Willenberg http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870804002932 give an explicit basis of space of high weight vectors, indexed by the LR tableaux.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Down from 33 seconds to 0.1 seconds for $\lambda=(2,1)$, $\mu=(2,2)$, $\nu=(1)$, $n=3$. Thanks!